# Mongoose index in model not working always but when I restart mongo service it works

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am indexing on two fields for their combination to be unique. 
But it doesnot works always, when I restart it mongo service it works again and it don't work after sometime.

This is how I define index in **model.js**

```
userSchema.index({ user_id: 1, name: 1 }, { unique: true });
```

When I check the index in mongo it disappears automatically after some time.
Unable to understand the issue whether the issue is of mongoose or my code.

Comment: "disappears automatically after some time" sounds quite odd.  You might try turning down the slowms setting by running `db.setProfilingLevel(0,0)` so that all operations are logged.  Then when the index disappears, you can examine the log to try to find out why.

Comment: Thanks @Joe this might help me find the issue that is causing it.

Comment: You're almost certainly dropping the database or the collection in your code, which drops indexes also. Mongoose ensures indexes exist when it boots, so when you're restarting your service it's recreating the index.